# Find Ole ClsId by file type

Tags: .net, com, ole

I need function that takes  data file  as byte array and detects it's COM Server Guid, how to find COM Server registered for this file type ?

Suppose I can enumerate all records in 
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID
and find it by file extension.

```
Guid GetClsId( byte[] fileData )
{
   var extension = TryGetExtensionByContent(fileData);

   /// enumerate HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID and search extension

   return foundedGuid;
}
```

But may be there more fast and universal ways to reach my goals ?

Answer (score 0):

[AssocQueryString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/bb773471(v=vs.85).aspx) should perform the task.

If there is an application registered for that extension you can check for the "open" command.

Comment: Thanks for response, but i can't found parameters for this function to extract Guid of OLE Server that registered for this extension ?